# Is there an application other than Adobe Digital Edition that will work with the e-book .ascm format my library provides?

Tags: 13.04, drm

The library provides a .ascm file for e-books. I need to get it into .epub format for my e-reader.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux).

Read here for further informations:
http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#how-do-i-use-purchased-epub-books-with-app-or-what-do-i-do-with-acsm-files